# Why I don't get any response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning NodeJS with express now. This is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const router = express.Router();
const response = require('./network/response')
var app = express();
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(router);


router.get('/message', (req, res) => {
    response.success(req, res, `Lista de mensajes 1000`);
})

router.post('/message', (req, res) => {

    if (req.query.error == 'ok') {
        response.error(req, res, `Error simulado`, 401)
    } else {
        response.success(req, res, `Creado correctamente`, 200);
    }

})

router.delete('/message', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Mensaje eliminado`);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`La aplicacion se esta escuchando en puerto 3000`);
})
```

and this is my network module:

```
exports.success = function (req, res, message, status) {
    res.status(status || 200).send({
        error: '',
        body: message
    });
}

exports.error = function (req, res, message, status) {
    res.status(status || 500).send({
        error: message,
        body: ''
    });
}
```

network module help me to have a better control of HTTP request. The problem is that when I make a POST request I never get the response, is just loading and loading. I am trying to get the **error** but nothing. This is the request:

> http://localhost:3000/message?error=ok

[image]

Comment: How are you actually submitting the POST request? (ie. are you using curl?)

Comment: @dave I am using postman and Insomnia too, I get the same error in both

Comment: @AmirPopovich I want to recieve the response.error no the response.success. To get the error I need to pass a query called error with value 'ok', I am doing it, but the petitions just loading loading and I never get the response.

Comment: as @AmirPopovich pointed out, the code seems to work fine. I got the same response he posted and `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` response as expected. I issued the API call through `curl -i -X POST http://localhost:3000/message\?error\=ok`.

Comment: The code looked good to me so I've copied it and ran in on my machine. The POST gives me a 401 response: `{"error":"Error simulado","body":""}`

Comment: Thanks @dave, I will restart postman to check

Comment: I still getting the same problem. I will publish a image.

Comment: I never restarted the server, because for some reason the **nodemon** did not do it automatically. I am sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is working mate.

check these curl requests :

> curl -XPOST -data '{"data":"data"}' http://localhost:3000/message
>
> curl: (3) Port number ended with '"'
>   {"error":"","body":"Creado correctamente"}

POSTMAN :
[image]

> curl -XPOST -data '{"data":"data"}' http://localhost:3000/message?error=ok
>
> curl: (3) Port number ended with '"'
>
> {"error":"Error simulado","body":""}